# R IBrokers. How to get currency contract to work in reqHistoricalData calls? e.g. CADUSD rates? And how to pull index prices? e.g. S&P, DJI?

Tags: r, trading, ibrokers

I am currently learning how to use the `IBrokers` package.

I can pull equity prices at frequencies I want, and option prices, but I'm currently stuck on pulling foreign exchange rates.

I don't know how to set up the right `twsContract`, for calling with `reqHistoricalData`.

I am interested in getting CADUSD currencies on say a 1 min basis.  How can I do this?

The example in the manual gives:

```
currency <- twsCurrency("EUR")
```

When I try and call this with say `reqHistoricalData(tws, currency)` it comes back with an error saying something like "no historical data available 1D".  As I can't even get the example in the manual to work, I'm rather stuck...

Can someone please enlighten me as to what the correct syntax is?  If I have a couple of examples that actually work, I can take it from there.

Also, when I try using `"USD.CAD"` or `"CAD.USD"` as the ticker in the `twsContract` object, I'm getting complaints that this isn't a valid security.  How can I find out what the right ticker name for `USD.CAD` would be?  Right now I figure out the ticket for stocks by looking at my interactive brokers application which is open at the same time obviously, and typing the company name and doing a search.  The ticker generally comes back e.g. (type apple, get back AAPL when I want to add this security to my portfolio in the interactive brokers workstation).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, another related question is how can I pull the historical of say the S&P500 price index on a 1 min basis say?

I am guessing I would use a `twsContract` object in R, but I don't know what parameters to use.  What should the ticker be?  The trade workstation mentions it's an "index" product type (obviously), which doesn't fit into any of the wrappers like `twsStock`, `twsCurrency` etc... Again, Is there an example of this somewhere, which actually works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having trouble getting data for FX because you're trying to get `TRADES` data which IBrokers does not disseminate for FX.  Instead, you should use `whatToShow="BID"` or `whatToShow="Ask"`.  e.g.

```
tws <- twsConnect()
ccy <- reqContractDetails(tws, twsCurrency("USD", "CAD"))[[1]]$contract
reqHistoricalData(tws, ccy, whatToShow='BID')
```

Getting data for the S&P 500 index is similar

```
reqHistoricalData(tws, reqContractDetails(tws, twsIndex("SPX", "CBOE", "USD"))[[1]]$contract)
```

Your question is pretty broad and reads like a request for an overview of the package.  Have you read the vignette? (`vignette("IBrokers")`)

---

I have a [package on R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1113) called **twsInstrument** that provides some wrappers to make things easier for you.

```
library(twsInstrument)
get_quote("USD.CAD")
getBAT("USD.CAD") #gets the last 5 days of minutely Bid/Ask/Trade/Midpoint
```

Also, see `?reqTBBOhistory` and `twsInstrument:::update.data` to download lots of data to disk.

Finally, I recommend asking these types of questions on the [r-sig-finance mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-finance) where Jeff is likely to see it.